# feature branch changes rebase

Tags: git, rebase

I have only one commit in the feature branch, ie. feature_1 and this feature branch changes are merged with the develop_1 branch. Now, I want to rebase this commit with the develop_2 branch.

How can I achieve that?

Please help.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to rebase commits once they have been merged. Make sure you really want to do this. Draw a graph of what you have now (see [Pretty Git branch graphs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1057564/1256452)).

Answer (score 0):

The ideal course of action would be to merge again:

Merge  `feature_1` to `develop_2` branch.

That is easier than rebasing `feature_1`, which would duplicate/replicate its commit on `develop_2`.

This assumes that `feature_1` was actually merged in `develop_1` (as stated in the OP), not *rebased* on top of `develop_1`.
Because if it was initially rebased, a second merge would not work (as it would effectively merge `develop_1` in `develop_2`)